# Selenium in Java cannot find ahref

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

please bear with me as I am new to automation, java and selenium!!

I have this piece of code:

```
<form role="form" id="contact-form" action="/" method="post">         
 <div class="row-home" >            
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left:0">
        <h3>New User?</h3>
            <p>It's easy to start using VocalEyes right away!</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="default/register">Register</a> </p>
     </div>
</div> </form>
```

And I am trying to click on the register button with various different combinations of .findelementby but I just can't it to work.  I keep getting the java error: 
  Unable to locate element:

There is another similar element on the page above the form:

```
<li><a href="/vocaleyes/default/register"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>  Register</a></li>
```

this is what I have tried (I resorted to the Selenium record/playback to get the xpaths):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='contact-form']/div/div/p[2]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/default/register')])[2])).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("btn.btn-primary")).click();
```

All of the above result in the same error.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`By.linkText()`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text) - it is easier, more explicit and readable:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register")).click();
```